# css, how to combine shape-outside and flex-wrap?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to combine flex-wrap and shape-outside to get something like this :

What i want to do is : the blue zone to flex-wrap it's content, and to be on the right and bottom of the grey zone :

[image]

adding `display: flex;` break the `shape-outside` 
Any tips ? thanks

A JSfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/81b3cLxf/

HTML

```
    <div class="main">
      <div class="left"></div>

      <div class="flex-container wrap">
        <div class="flex-item">1</div>
        <div class="flex-item">2</div>
        <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        <div class="flex-item">4</div>
        <div class="flex-item">5</div>
        <div class="flex-item">6</div>
        <div class="flex-item">7</div>
        <div class="flex-item">8</div>
      </div> 
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .main {
      width: 600px;
      height: 500px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: black;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .left {
      width: 50%;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: lightgray; 
      shape-outside:"none";
      float: left;

    }


    .flex-container {
       height: 100%;
      background-color: blue;
      -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -moz-flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
    }


    .wrap    { 
      -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }  

    .flex-item {
      background: tomato;
      padding: 5px;
      width:  75px;
      height: 75px;
      margin: 10px;  
      line-height: 75px;
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 2em;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `grid` instead.

Comment: can grid be used only in the "blue zone" ?

Comment: shape outside can only be used with float and what you are showing is a perfect float case

Comment: the "left" class use float yes. i want to make it work what ever it used. i used float +shape-outside + flex wrap because i found this but maybe it's the wrong way.

Comment: you cannot, if you use flex then you can no more rely on shape outside

Comment: ok at least i stop looking in this way, you think i can do it in another way? thanks

Comment: use float even from the elements (or inline-block) inside the other container and remove the flex container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check my example with `grid`:

```css
.main {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.left {
  grid-column: span 3;
  grid-row: span 2;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.flex-container {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(75px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 85px;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="flex-container wrap">
    <div class="left"></div>

    <div class="flex-item">1</div>
    <div class="flex-item">2</div>
    <div class="flex-item">3</div>
    <div class="flex-item">4</div>
    <div class="flex-item">5</div>
    <div class="flex-item">6</div>
    <div class="flex-item">7</div>
    <div class="flex-item">8</div>
    <div class="flex-item">9</div>
    <div class="flex-item">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post a complete here here. That includes a [mcve] and an explanation. Posting your answer on a third party site has no value if that site is down, goes away, or is inaccessible.

Comment: i don't know who down vote... 
perfectly what i want thank you :)